# ReferenceError: self is not defined in nodejs module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to reuse same function defined within the same class but I am getting error `self` is not defined. Can anyone suggest what is the correct approach to call a function in nodejs module.

Here is my code,

```
class addresses{
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.plural = 'addresses';
    this.singular = 'address';
}

parseCoordinates(arr) {
   arr.forEach(function (value, index) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        self.parseCoordinates(value); // Error at this line
    } else if (!isNaN(parseFloat(value))) {
        arr[index] = (+value);
    }
  });
 }
}
module.exports = new addresses();
```

Comment: did you tried using `this` ?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be defined?

Comment: @CodeManiac — `this` won't work in a callback like that

Comment: Confusing with Python habits maybe?

Comment: tried `this` got the error like not defined.

Comment: Several solutions: (1) add `var self = this` as statement before `arr.forEach`. Or (2) make callback an arrow function, replacing  `function (value, index)` with `(value, index) =>` and replace `self` with `this`. Or some solution with `bind`, ...